# Map Reduce for Firebase Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, mapreduce

I have a Firebase collection with Documents that contains amounts of an income or expense operation. I want to get the sum (positive or negative value) within a date range. For example a month, or just beetwen two dates.
I thought that Firebase Functions could help, but now they are available only inside payment plan (I use the Free Spark).

So, I have to fetch all data to the client side and only then calculate.
Is that solution an optimal or there is an another good strategy?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What's the problem with doing that calculation on the client? It's really just a series of numbers and even several thousand results would be a tiny amount of data if it was properly structured. Do you have some code thats not working or a structure that's problematic? Just trying to understand the question. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the firebase cloud functions you can only download all and cound localy. I would still reconsider to switch to the "pay as you go" plan.

By downloading all data to count it you would hit very fast the free ter limit.

When using cloud functions just for the SUM of a collection you probably won't get charged because the cloud functions also have a free tier.

You can always set a warning if the Firebase/Google Project costs in a month reach a specific amount/budget. [This](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/billing/avoid-surprise-bills) can help you with that.